# Accessing data in a promise array

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have a promise array that I need to use for comparing and the sort. However I can't seem it use it.

```
Promise {
  RowDataPacket {
  userid: 'id',
  username: 'name',
  password: 'pass',
  email: 'email',
  rank: 5,
  title: 'Squire' } }
```

This array is assigned to `data`.

I've tried `data[0]` to just get the row data. returned `undefined` I then just tried using properties `data.username` also returns as `undefined`... how exactly am I supposed to use this array?

Comment: That's not valid gain or JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are trying to access an array that is inside of a Promise object, correct? To access the data, assuming the Promise is assigned to the variable, `data`, you can do

```
data.then( dataArray => doStuffWithArray(dataArray) )
```

Here's a good article about [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) you can go over to gain a better understanding of how a Promise is used and functions.

Comment: Yeah thats not going to work. I don;t like using the `.then()` because everything I do in there stays in there. If I assign a value to a variable inside that, and then try to use it out of it it just doesn't work. I may just have to rewrite this whole thing again. It's quite annoying I'm having to use promises already, just trying to compare usernames from a query.

Comment: LOL. It's not about liking it's about how promises work.

Comment: You can use async / await, https://javascript.info/async-await, to be able to access your data outside of a promise, but those also use promises under the hood. This is the closest you can get do to get around that issue with variables being scoped inside of a promise.

Comment: If you don't like the fact that the asynchronous result "stays" in the then function, then don't do asynchronous programming.  It's not hard, really, just stop doing network connections, database requests, user input...